# How to add data in one spreadsheet making a database and in another update/overwrite?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Daily, I receive a spreadsheet with two tabs of data. Each one has about 9 thousand rows. I need to capture the data from this worksheet and generate two new spreadsheets with one for "daily reporting" (with only the data of this day) and another for create a "database" (with all data previous results). How can I do this automatically with GAS?

Working on this project I can already extract the data from the spreadsheets that I receive and generate a spreadsheet with the data of it, but I want to automate the following process:

1. generate a spreadsheet "daily" with the data of the day (last update). In this case, the new data have to subscribe the last data.
2. generate a spreadsheet "database" with all data, in this case, the new data must increment on the last row, and will storage all the previous data.

Working in this project, I create this code but I don´t know how to do these things, if anyone could help me, I really appreciate!

```
function getDay() {
  var day = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxxx');
  var tab1 = day.getSheets()[0];
  var tab2 = day.getSheets()[1];

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sss = ss.getSheets()[0];

  var weeks = tab1.getRange("G8").getValues();
  var dates = tab1.getRange("G9").getValues();
  var regions = tab1.getRange('A10:A').getValues(); 
  var locnames = tab1.getRange('B10:B').getValues();
  var locnums = tab1.getRange('C10:C').getValues();
  var divisions = tab1.getRange('D10:D').getValues();
  var depnums = tab1.getRange('E10:E').getValues();
  var depnames = tab1.getRange('F10:F').getValues();
  var saless = tab1.getRange('G10:G').getValues();
  var qtys = tab2.getRange('G10:G').getValues();

  var datestart = sss.getRange('A2').setValues(dates);
  var dateend = sss.getRange('B2').setValues(dates);
  var week = sss.getRange('C2').setValues(weeks);
  var regions = sss.getRange(2,4,regions.length,regions[0].length).setValues(regions);
  var locname = sss.getRange(2,5,locnames.length,locnames[0].length).setValues(locnames);
  var locnum = sss.getRange(2,6,locnums.length,locnums[0].length).setValues(locnums);
  var division = sss.getRange(2,7,divisions.length,divisions[0].length).setValues(divisions);
  var depnum = sss.getRange(2,8,depnums.length,depnums[0].length).setValues(depnums);
  var depname = sss.getRange(2,9,depnames.length,depnames[0].length).setValues(depnames);
  var sales = sss.getRange(2,10,saless.length,saless[0].length).setValues(saless);
  var qty = sss.getRange(2,11,qtys.length,qtys[0].length).setValues(qtys);

 }
```

I put a spreadsheet in the link to illustrate the format of sheets and what I need to do. The first two tabs are the same as the ones I get. And in the next two tabs(daily_report, database) are the worksheets that I want to get separately with the code. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_iz0oansAfINosV2qNoDG0QMNpGS1bp1AL5kJQztRtc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Tags should not be forced in titles. By the other hand, have you considered that Google Sheets spreadsheets could have a maximum of 2 million cells?

Answer (score 0):

First add all the values you want to put in a row in an array []. You can add this row to the wanted sheet with sheet.appendRow(row)

For the daily needed you can make add a trigger which will run your programm daily with the little clock icon.